# In ios how can I get the current day?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, nsarray

I'm trying to make a 'daily bible verse' feature in my app where it shows you a new bible verse everyday. I am planning on making an nsarray with like 100 strings which would be 100 bible verses, and then once a day it shows you a different bible verse, how can i do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [gregorian components:(NSHourCalendarUnit  | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit) fromDate:yourDateHere];
NSInteger hour = [dateComponents hour];
NSInteger minute = [dateComponents minute];
NSInteger second = [dateComponents second];
```

**Swift**

```
let calendar = Calendar.current
let dateComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.hour, .minute, .second], from: date)
let hour = dateComponents.hour
let minute = dateComponents.minute
let second = dateComponents.second
```

Answer (score 2):

`[NSDate date]` gives you the current date and time.  You can format it with NSDateFormatter.  (Please Google for examples before asking how to use NSDateFormatter here.)

Answer (score 0):

Like Licks said **[NSDate date]** can get current date and time, and ** [NSDateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)** can format the date, here is is example

```
NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterBehaviorDefault];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"];
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSString * s = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
```

result:
2012-11-15 16:54